# Make Rails asset behaviour dependent on Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I'm wondering if there's any way for a Rails asset to vary according to the environment.

Something like:

```
function log(m) {
  <% if Rails.env=='development' %>
    console.log(m)
  <% end %>
}
```

And similarly, you could show a special message or color scheme by making environment-specific features in the stylesheet.

(I realize assets are compiled in production, which is why I'm not expecting to do this with any arbitrary Ruby code while the server's running. But I wonder if there's a way to do it with the environment at least.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see [Asset Pipeline, Preprocessing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing)

### Dynamic Javascript

in your javascript manifest file **app/assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//...
//= dynamic_js
//...
```

in **app/assets/javascripts/dynamic_js.js.erb**

```
function log(m) {
  <% if Rails.env=='development' %>
    console.log(m)
  <% end %>
}
```

### Dynamic CSS

in your stylesheet manifest: **app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*...
*= dynamic_css
*/
```

in **app/assets/stylesheets/dynamic_css.css.erb**

```
.environment-color {
  <% if Rails.env == 'development' %>
    color: <%= 'red' %>
  <% else %>
    color: <%= 'white' %>
  <% end %>
}
```